# Google Cloud SDK on Cygwin [Errno 128] Transport endpoint is not connected>

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying install Google Cloud SDK on Cygwin in Windows 8. I strictly follow the steps in https://developers.google.com/cloud/sdk/ but met the following error message. Does anybody know how to solve it? Thank you.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Creating update staging area...

Installing: BigQuery Command Line Tool ... The component [bq] failed to download.

urlopen error [Errno 128] Transport endpoint is not connected
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Comment: At what step in the linked instructions do you encounter the error?

Comment: I run curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash, automatically, ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh executed. Specifically, the error occurs after I choose the 4th option - "no App Engine".

Answer (score 0):

Weird thing happened. When I turn on my computer today, the problem is solved. But still, I do not know what causes the problem.